# How can I keep my Linux program running after I exit ssh of my non-root user?

Tags: linux, debian

I've searched, googled, sat in IRC for a week and even talked to a friend who is devoutly aligned with linux but I haven't yet received a solid answer.

I have written a shell script that runs as soon as I log into my non-root user and runs basically just does "./myprogram &" without quotation. When I exit shh my program times out and I am unable to connect to it until I log back in. How can I keep my program running after I exit SSH of my non-root user?

I am curious if this has to be done on the program level or what? My apologizes if this does not belong here, I am not sure where it goes to be perfectly honest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beside using `nohup`, you can run your program  in terminal multiplexer like [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/). With them, you can reattach to sessions, which is for example quite helpful if you need to run terminal-based interactive programs or long time running scripts over a unstable ssh connections.

[`boybu`](https://launchpad.net/byobu) is a nice enhancement of `screen`.

Comment: +1 for considering interactive processes. also first I've heard of `boybu`... sounds interesting

Answer (score 3):

Try nohup: http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup

Likely your program receives a SIGHUP signal when you exit your ssh session.

Answer (score 2):

There's two signals that can cause your program to die after your `ssh` session ends: `SIGHUP` and `SIGPIPE`.

`SIGHUP` will be sent to your program because the parent process (`ssh`) has died. You can get around this either by using the program `nohup` (i.e. `nohup ./myprogram &`) or by using the shell builtin `disown` (`./myprogram& disown`)

`SIGPIPE` will be sent to your program if it tries to write to `stdout` or `stderr` after the `ssh` session has been disconnected. To get around this, redirect them to a file or `/dev/null`, i.e. `nohup ./myprogram >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &`

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to use the [batch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/batch) (or `at`) command, in addition to the other answers (`nohup`, `screen`, ...). And `ssh` has a `-f` option which might interest you.